# Using a select_tag for hours and minutes to be together, how would I attribute that to the day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't like the Rails out-of-the-box date selection where you can choose hours, seconds, and minutes. What I'd like is just hours and minutes together iterated in half hour increments. Like so :

```
def time_selection
  options = []
  48.times do |i|
    time = DateTime.now.beginning_of_day + (i*30.minutes)
    options << [time.strftime('%I:M %p'), time.strftime('%I:M %p')]
  end
  options_for_select(options, "[:scheduled_at(4i)]")
end
```

Then my HTML :

```
.formRowTask
  = f.label :scheduled_at, "Date"
  = f.date_select :scheduled_at, :start_year => 1.year.ago.year, :end_year => 15.years.from_now.year
.formRowTask
  .time-selection-container
    = select_tag :sheculed_at, time_selection, :class => "duration_unit time-selection"
```

But now I would like to make sure that this time gets allocated properly with the other selection box where users can choose a date. And both the date and time go with the `[:scheduled_at]` attribute.

My question is, how would I concatenate this information with the date so that it is a datetime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few acceptable solutions to this.  Personally, I would create two virtual attributes in the model: "scheduled_date" and "scheduled_time" to use in your view and then in a callback (ex: before_save) parse each to create the DateTime scheduled_at for persistence to the db.

ex: I don't know what your data actually looks like when it gets to the model but if scheduled_date came in as '%m/%d/%Y' and time as '%I:%M %p'  your model and the method in the callback could look like:

```
attr_accessor :scheduled_date, :scheduled_time #to use in your view

before_save :set_scheduled_at  #to parse both items into one attribute

def set_scheduled_at
  self.scheduled_at = DateTime.strptime("#{scheduled_date}-#{scheduled_time}", '%m/%d/%Y-%I:%M %p')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it right way, consider monkey patching [DateTimeSelector](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L638).

If you want quick and dirty solution, just make sure that your inputs for hours and minutes have same names as `date_select` generates, but with (4i) for hours, (5i) for minutes and (6i) for seconds.

So for example, if your object is an instance of `Task`, the form has to be like this:

```
<div class="formRowTask">
  <label for="task_scheduled_at">Date</label>
  <select id="task_scheduled_at_3i" name="task[scheduled_at(3i)]">...</select>
  <select id="task_scheduled_at_2i" name="task[scheduled_at(2i)]">...</select>
  <select id="task_scheduled_at_1i" name="task[scheduled_at(1i)]">...</select>
</div>
<div class="formRowTask">
  <div class="time-selection-container">
    <select name="task[scheduled_at(4i)]">...</select>
    <select name="task[scheduled_at(5i)]">...</select>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to pass `name` parameter is, again, depends. You can write special helper for that or just simply pass:

```
select_tag :scheduled_minutes, time_selection, :name => 'task[scheduled_at(4i)]'
```